# stdWrap.outerwrap in Tmenu in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i have a question about the stdwrap in my menu. Here is my code:

```
ib.nav.main = HMENU
lib.nav.main {
1 = TMENU
1 {
    wrap =  <ul class="menu sitemenu-submenu-light sitemenu-extra-strong sitemenu-extra-no-arrows">|</ul>
    expAll = 1
    noBlur = 1
    NO = 1
    NO {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        ATagParams = class="menu-item menu-separator"
    }
    ACT < .NO
    ACT = 1
    ACT{
       wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current">|</li>
   }
}
2 = TMENU
2 {
    expAll = 1
    stdWrap.outerWrap = <ul>|</ul>
    NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
    noBlur = 1
    NO.ATagParams = class="menu-item"
    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB {
        allWrap = <div class="mega-menu mega-section"><h4 data-role="title">|</h4></div>
        ATagParams = class="menu-item"
        before.cObject = LOAD_REGISTER
        before.cObject.hasSubmenu = TEXT
        before.cObject.hasSubmenu.value = 1
    }
    stdWrap.outerWrap.override.if.isTrue.data = REGISTER:hasSubmenu
    stdWrap.outerWrap.override = <div class="mega" data-columns="5">|</div>
    wrap.override.if.isTrue.data = REGISTER:hasSubmenu
}
```

As far as it goes (and as far as i understand it), will this code override my ul with a div, if there is a third level in the navigation. However, this seems to break my layout in the same way, as if i wrote this line without the override:

```
stdWrap.outerWrap = <div>|</div>
```

As i learned, i have to put "li" tags in an ul or typoscript breaks the layout and puts in random "li" tags everywhere. However, as i understand my override, it should only replace the ul with the div when there are submenus. It would be interesting to know, why typoscript is behaving this way, when i put "li" tags inside a div (which is wrong, i know ~ usually by templating this won't destroy my template though) and why my override is behaving in such a way. I thought maybe, that i have to reset the value of my Register as it always may be set but i didn't find a way to do so.

edit:

resulting html:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="site-main-nav">
   <ul class="-menu sitemenu-submenu-light sitemenu-extra-strong sitemenu-extra-no-arrows">
      <li class="current mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=74" class="menu-item menu-separator">Unternehmen</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="index.php?id=78" class="menu-item">Stark im Verbund</a></li>
              <li><a href="index.php?id=90" class="menu-item">Unternehmensbild</a></li>
              <li><a href="index.php?id=91" class="menu-item">Auf einem Blick</a></li>
              <li><a href="index.php?id=92" class="menu-item">Zalhen / Daten / Fakten</a></li>
              <li><a href="index.php?id=93" class="menu-item">Mitbestimmung</a></li>
              <li><a href="index.php?id=94" class="menu-item">Soziale Verantwortung</a></li>
              <li><a href="index.php?id=95" class="menu-item">International</a></li>
              <li><a href="index.php?id=96" class="menu-item">Personen</a></li>
              <li><a href="index.php?id=97" class="menu-item">Imagebroschüre</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=75" class="menu-item menu-separator">Mitglieder</a>
       <div class="-mega" data-columns="5">
          <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=82" class="menu-item">Warenprogramme</a></h4>
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="index.php?id=102" class="menu-item">Industriepartner</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.php?id=103" class="menu-item">Starseller</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?id=104" class="menu-item">Voting</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?id=105" class="menu-item">Mandatmodell</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?id=106" class="menu-item">Topseller</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?id=107" class="menu-item">Listing</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?id=108" class="menu-item">Sport</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?id=109" class="menu-item">Exclusivmarken</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=98" class="menu-item">Messe-
         &amp; Ordercenter</a></h4>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php?id=110" class="menu-item"> Campus</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?id=111" class="menu-item">Messen auf einem Blick</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=112" class="menu-item"> First Order</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=113" class="menu-item"> Fashion Days</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=114" class="menu-item"> auf der GDS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=115" class="menu-item">Rundreise</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=116" class="menu-item">Termine</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=99" class="menu-item">Fachberatung</a>
                            </h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=117" class="menu-item">Strategie/Sortiment</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=118" class="menu-item">Lieferantenanalyse</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=119" class="menu-item">Betriebsvergleich</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=120" class="menu-item">Seminare &amp; Trainings</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=121" class="menu-item">Unternehmensberatung</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=122" class="menu-item">Steuerberatung</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=123" class="menu-item">Rechtsberatung</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=124" class="menu-item">ERFA-Tagung</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=125" class="menu-item">Prozessberatung</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=100" class="menu-item">Finanzen</a></h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=126" class="menu-item">DZB ZR</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=127" class="menu-item">DZB Finanz</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=128" class="menu-item">DZB Cash</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=101" class="menu-item">Marketing</a></h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=130" class="menu-item">Marketingbausteine</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=131" class="menu-item">Saisonwerbung</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=132" class="menu-item">Homepage-Baukasten</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=76" class="menu-item menu-separator">Industriepartner</a>

                        <div class="-mega" data-columns="5">
                            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=134" class="menu-item">Warenprogramme</a></h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=142" class="menu-item">Industriepartner</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=141" class="menu-item">Starseller</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=140" class="menu-item">Voting</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=139" class="menu-item">Mandatmodell</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=138" class="menu-item">Topseller</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=137" class="menu-item">Listing</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=136" class="menu-item">Sport</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=135" class="menu-item">Exclusivmarken</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=143" class="menu-item">Messe- &amp; Ordercenter</a></h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=150" class="menu-item"> Campus</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=149" class="menu-item">Messen auf einem Blick</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=148" class="menu-item"> First Order</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=147" class="menu-item"> Fashion Days</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=146" class="menu-item"> auf der GDS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=145" class="menu-item">Rundreise</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=144" class="menu-item">Termine</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=151" class="menu-item">Dienstleistungen</a></h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=153" class="menu-item">Industriepartner-Marketing</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=154" class="menu-item">Prozessberatung</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=155" class="menu-item">Lieferantenförderung</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=152" class="menu-item">Finanzen</a></h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.php?id=156" class="menu-item">Zentralregulierung</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=157" class="menu-item">Links</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <li class="mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=83" class="menu-item menu-separator">News</a>
            <div class="-mega" data-columns="5"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php?id=158" class="menu-item"> News</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?id=159" class="menu-item"> in der Presse</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?id=160" class="menu-item">Foto-&amp; Videogalerie</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?id=161" class="menu-item">Schuhverliebt</a></li>
    </div>
    <li class="mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=77" class="menu-item menu-separator">Händlersuche</a></li>
    <li class="mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=88" class="menu-item menu-separator">Karriere</a>

        <div class="-mega" data-columns="5"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.php?id=162" class="menu-item">Stellenangebote</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?id=163" class="menu-item">Die  als Arbeitgeber</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?id=164" class="menu-item">Ausbildung</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?id=165" class="menu-item">Duales Studium</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?id=166" class="menu-item">Direkteinstieg</a></li>
```

expected HTML:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="site-main-nav">
<ul class="-menu sitemenu-submenu-light sitemenu-extra-strong sitemenu-extra-no-arrows">
    <li class="current mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=74" class="menu-item menu-separator">Unternehmen</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php?id=78" class="menu-item">Stark im Verbund</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?id=90" class="menu-item">Unternehmensbild</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?id=91" class="menu-item">Auf einem Blick</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?id=92" class="menu-item">Zalhen / Daten / Fakten</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?id=93" class="menu-item">Mitbestimmung</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?id=94" class="menu-item">Soziale Verantwortung</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?id=95" class="menu-item">International</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?id=96" class="menu-item">Personen</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?id=97" class="menu-item">Imagebroschüre</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=75" class="menu-item menu-separator">Mitglieder</a>
        <div class="-mega" data-columns="5">
            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=82" class="menu-item">Warenprogramme</a>
            </h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=102" class="menu-item">Industriepartner</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=103" class="menu-item">Starseller</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=104" class="menu-item">Voting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=105" class="menu-item">Mandatmodell</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=106" class="menu-item">Topseller</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=107" class="menu-item">Listing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=108" class="menu-item">Sport</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=109" class="menu-item">Exclusivmarken</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=98" class="menu-item">Messe- &amp;
                Ordercenter</a></h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=110" class="menu-item"> Campus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=111" class="menu-item">Messen auf einem Blick</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=112" class="menu-item"> First Order</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=113" class="menu-item"> Fashion Days</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=114" class="menu-item"> auf der GDS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=115" class="menu-item">Rundreise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=116" class="menu-item">Termine</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=99" class="menu-item">Fachberatung</a>
            </h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=117" class="menu-item">Strategie/Sortiment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=118" class="menu-item">Lieferantenanalyse</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=119" class="menu-item">Betriebsvergleich</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=120" class="menu-item">Seminare &amp; Trainings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=121" class="menu-item">Unternehmensberatung</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=122" class="menu-item">Steuerberatung</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=123" class="menu-item">Rechtsberatung</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=124" class="menu-item">ERFA-Tagung</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=125" class="menu-item">Prozessberatung</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=100" class="menu-item">Finanzen</a></h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=126" class="menu-item">DZB ZR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=127" class="menu-item">DZB Finanz</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=128" class="menu-item">DZB Cash</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=101" class="menu-item">Marketing</a></h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=130" class="menu-item">Marketingbausteine</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=131" class="menu-item">Saisonwerbung</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=132" class="menu-item">Homepage-Baukasten</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=76" class="menu-item menu-separator">Industriepartner</a>

        <div class="-mega" data-columns="5">
            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=134" class="menu-item">Warenprogramme</a>
            </h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=142" class="menu-item">Industriepartner</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=141" class="menu-item">Starseller</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=140" class="menu-item">Voting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=139" class="menu-item">Mandatmodell</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=138" class="menu-item">Topseller</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=137" class="menu-item">Listing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=136" class="menu-item">Sport</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=135" class="menu-item">Exclusivmarken</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=143" class="menu-item">Messe- &amp;
                Ordercenter</a></h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=150" class="menu-item"> Campus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=149" class="menu-item">Messen auf einem Blick</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=148" class="menu-item"> First Order</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=147" class="menu-item"> Fashion Days</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=146" class="menu-item"> auf der GDS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=145" class="menu-item">Rundreise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=144" class="menu-item">Termine</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=151" class="menu-item">Dienstleistungen</a>
            </h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=153" class="menu-item">Industriepartner-Marketing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=154" class="menu-item">Prozessberatung</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=155" class="menu-item">Lieferantenförderung</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mega-menu -mega-section"><h4 data-role="title"><a href="index.php?id=152" class="menu-item">Finanzen</a></h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php?id=156" class="menu-item">Zentralregulierung</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="index.php?id=157" class="menu-item">Links</a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=83" class="menu-item menu-separator">News</a>
        <div class="-mega" data-columns="5">
            <a href="index.php?id=158" class="menu-item"> News</a>
            <a href="index.php?id=159" class="menu-item"> in der Presse</a>
            <a href="index.php?id=160" class="menu-item">Foto-&amp;Videogalerie</a>
            <a href="index.php?id=161" class="menu-item">Schuhverliebt</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=77" class="menu-item menu-separator">Händlersuche</a></li>
    <li class="mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=88" class="menu-item menu-separator">Karriere</a>

        <div class="-mega" data-columns="5">
            <a href="index.php?id=162" class="menu-item">Stellenangebote</a>
            <a href="index.php?id=163" class="menu-item">Die  als Arbeitgeber</a>
            <a href="index.php?id=164" class="menu-item">Ausbildung</a>
            <a href="index.php?id=165" class="menu-item">Duales Studium</a>
            <a href="index.php?id=166" class="menu-item">Direkteinstieg</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu"><a href="index.php?id=89" class="menu-item menu-separator">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post your resulting and your expected HTML .

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I updated my question with the expected and the resulting html. As you can see, the resulting html puts in lis even outside the <nav> tag. The expected behaiviour would give me a navigation and as soon as it the navigation has 3 layers, it creates a wide navigation box on hover and adds the second layer as headlines of the third layer (hard to describe, i could upload an image though, if it is important)

Answer (score 1):

You must have an `<ul>` around `<li>`. Please also mind the order of the `stdWrap`.
You can find nice cheat sheets on the official documentation (`stdWrap overview for cObjects` and `stdWrap overview for menu objects`): http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CheatSheets.html

After you update your question, here is the update to the answer.

`TypoScript` does not care about your HTML. `TypoScript` ist not smart at all. It will just create any `string` and you define. If your resulting HTML is wrong, that means your instructions to the `page renderer` (that is what `TypoScript` is) are wrong. You need to check what gets generated where and how this is attached together to form the final `string` that is returned to the browser.

Please post the broken and the expected HTML.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, especially for the link. I will look into that. I formed my question poorly though. I tried too many things and posted a wrong code snipped. I will update it accordingly.